# BASH SHELL print columns with specific order

Tags: unix, awk, printing

I have this file :

```
933|Mahinda|Perera|male|1989-12-03|2010-03-17T13:32:10.447+0000|192.248.2.123|Firefox
1129|Carmen|Lepland|female|1984-02-18|2010-02-28T04:39:58.781+0000|81.25.252.111|Internet Explorer
4194|Há»“ ChÃ­|Do|male|1988-10-14|2010-03-17T22:46:17.657+0000|103.10.89.118|Internet Explorer
8333|Chen|Wang|female|1980-02-02|2010-03-15T10:21:43.365+0000|1.4.16.148|Internet Explorer
8698|Chen|Liu|female|1982-05-29|2010-02-21T08:44:41.479+0000|14.103.81.196|Firefox
8853|Albin|Monteno|male|1986-04-09|2010-03-19T21:52:36.860+0000|178.209.14.40|Internet Explorer
10027|Ning|Chen|female|1982-12-08|2010-02-22T17:59:59.221+0000|1.2.9.86|Firefox
```

and with this order 
`./tool.sh --browsers -f <file>`

i want to count the number of the browsers in specific order , for example :

```
Chrome 143
Firefox 251
Internet Explorer 67
```

i use this command :

```
   if [ "$1" == "--browsers" -a "$2" == "-f"  -a  "$4" == "" ]
then
 awk -F'|' '{print $8}' $3 | sort | uniq -c | awk '  {print $2 , $3 , $1} '
fi
```

but it works only for 3 arguments. How to make it work for many arguments? for example a browser with 4 words or more

Comment: Are you asking how to sort your file, or how to process arguments?

Comment: both .. how can i print the number of counts of browsers in the right with one space  and with browsers with more than 3 words

Comment: I don't see how your sample data could possibly produce those results; I don't see 143 counts of "Chrome", for instance. Also, what is the meaning of your arguments? What are you actually trying to achieve with these arguments?

Comment: look. I have a longer file the truth is , so thats why there are more browsers.
well, these arguments are the $1 = 143 , $2 = chrome $3 = " " . 
, but if a browser in column 8 ( $8) has more than 4 words , it prints only till $3 ... how can i make it print more $ in row like :  browser 1 ( the name of the browser , and the number of counts of this browser with one space between them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like an awk one-liner to count your browsers:

```
$ awk -F'|' '{a[$8]++} END{for(i in a){printf("%s %d\n",i,a[i])}}' inputfile
Firefox 3
Internet Explorer 4
```

This increments elements of an array, then at the end of the file steps through the array and prints the totals.  If you want the output sorted, you can just pipe it through `sort`. I don't see a problem with multiple words in a browser name.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
awk -F"|" '{print $8}' in | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2,$1}'
```

where `in` is the input file.

output

```
[myShell] ➤ awk -F"|" '{print $8}' in | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2,$1}'
Firefox 3
Internet 4
```

also for parsing argument is better to use `getopts`

i.e.

```
#!/bin/bash
function usage {
  echo "usage: ..."
}

while getopts b:o:h opt; do
  case $opt in
    b)
      fileName=$OPTARG
      echo "filename[$fileName]"
      awk -F"|" '{print $8}' $fileName | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2,$1}'
      ;;
    o)
      otherargs=$OPTARG
      echo "otherargs[$otherargs]"
      ;;
    h)
      usage && exit 0
      ;;
    ?)
      usage && exit 2
      ;;
  esac
done
```

output

```
[myShell] ➤ ./arg -b in
filename[in]
Firefox 3
Internet 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Your final Awk hard-codes two fields; just continue with `$4, $5, $6` etc to print more fields. However, this will add a spurious space for each comma.

Better yet, since the first field is fixed width (because that's the output format from `uniq -c`), you can do `print substr($0,8), $1`

Answer (score -1):

I'd do it in perl:

```
#!/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %count_of;
while ( <> ) { 
   chomp;
   $count_of{(split /\|/)[7]}++; 
}

print Dumper \%count_of;
```

This can be cut down to a one liner:

```
perl -F'\|' -lane '$c{$F[7]++}; END{ print "$_ => $c{$_}" for keys %c }'
```